# c# MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 Encryption Decryption Class in php

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to convert c# application into php but I stuck at a place where C# provides Security class for Encryption and decryption based on RIJNDAEL algo. I am trying to convert into php.

**Note:** I am Using php 7.2 so mcrypt is deprecated for this version.

**C# code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pharmarackencryption
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string initVector = "aw90rela942f65u2";

        // This constant is used to determine the keysize of the encryption algorithm.
        private const int keysize = 256;

        public static string Encrypt(string plainText, string passPhrase = "testing")
        {
            byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(initVector);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherTextBytes);
        }

        public static string Decrypt(string cipherText, string passPhrase = "testing")
        {
            byte[] initVectorBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(initVector);
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, null);
            byte[] keyBytes = password.GetBytes(keysize / 8);
            RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged();
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, initVectorBytes);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes);
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
            int decryptedByteCount = cryptoStream.Read(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextBytes, 0, decryptedByteCount);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            string enc_password = Encrypt("437217");
            string dec_password = Decrypt("C9xJGa03dRQx9ePm0nLnHg==");
            Console.WriteLine(enc_password);
            Console.WriteLine(dec_password);
        }
    }
}
```

**Encryption : C9xJGa03dRQx9ePm0nLnHg==**

I found some what similar code in php like

**PHP code:**

```
<?php 
    // key/iv in ASCII binary data, $str base64
    function decrypt_stuff($key, $str, $iv) {
        // $plaintext_dec = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, base64_decode($str), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
        $plaintext_dec = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($str), "aes-256-cbc", $key,  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
        return $plaintext_dec;
    }

    // key/iv in ascii binary data, $str ascii
    function encrypt_stuff($key, $str, $iv) {
        // $ciphertext = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));
        if (($l = (strlen($str) & 15)) > 0) { $str .= str_repeat(chr(0), 16 - $l); }
        $ciphertext = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($str, "aes-256-cbc", $key,  OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv));
        return $ciphertext;
    }

    echo encrypt_stuff("testing","437217","aw90rela942f65u2");
    //Result : LTbhEHjFgfa5PDJQXJEdKQ==
```

Both are going same thing but still result is different

Comment: You can move back to version 7.0, there is not a major difference but you will find mcrypt in that version

Comment: openssl_encrypt is alternative to mcrypt

Comment: Thanks i never knew that.

Comment: you might want to double-check padding

Comment: @sh4dowb, I already checked padding but still results are different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your PHP code produces different results because you're not using the same key. In your C# code you're using `PasswordDeriveBytes` to create the key, which is Microsoft's implementation of PBKDF1.

PHP doesn't support PBKDF1, but we could write a function that is compatible with C#. The code below is inspired from this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27791726/encryption-diff-between-java-and-c-sharp/27798812#27798812) by Maarten Bodewes, translated to PHP.

```
function passwordDeriveBytes($password, $salt, $iterations = 100, $len = 32) {
    $key = $password . $salt;
    for($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        $key = sha1($key, true);
    }
    if (strlen($key) < $len) {
        $hx = passwordDeriveBytes($password, $salt, $iterations - 1, 20);
        $counter = 0;
        while (strlen($key) < $len) {
            $counter += 1;
            $key .= sha1($counter . $hx, true);
        }
    }
    return substr($key, 0, $len);
}
```

Also, you're bese64 encoding and padding your data manually. You're preforming zero byte padding, but in your C# code you're using PKCS7 (the default and preferred) padding. It's best to let `openssl` pad and encode your data.

```
function encrypt_stuff($key, $str, $iv) {
    return openssl_encrypt($str, "aes-256-cbc", $key, 0, $iv);
}

function decrypt_stuff($key, $str, $iv) {
    return openssl_decrypt($str, "aes-256-cbc", $key, 0, $iv);
}
```

Using the key derived from `passwordDeriveBytes`, this PHP code produces the same results as your C# code.

```
$key = passwordDeriveBytes("testing", null);
$enc = encrypt_stuff($key,"437217","aw90rela942f65u2");
echo $enc;
//C9xJGa03dRQx9ePm0nLnHg==
```

However, I don't recommend using this code for the following reasons.

- It's best to use PBKDF2 for your key. You can use [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.105).aspx) in C#:

  ```
  Rfc2898DeriveBytes kdf = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations);
  byte[] key = kdf.GetBytes(32);
  ```

  and [`hash_pbkdf2`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-pbkdf2.php) in PHP:

  ```
  $key = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $password, $salt, $iterations, 32, true);
  ```

  The salt should be at least 8 bytes long, and the number of iterations should be at least 10,000.
- You're not using a salt. You should use a random salt for each password, it makes your keys stronger.
- You're using a static IV. The IV should be unique and unpredictable. You can create a random IV with [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.105).aspx):

  ```
  byte[] iv = new byte[16];
  RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider(); 
  rng.GetBytes(iv);
  ```

  and [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php):

  ```
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
  ```

  You could use this code for the salt too.
- You're not using authenticated encryption. If you're using PHP 7 you could use GCM, but unfortunately .NET doesn't provide any AEAD algorithms. However, you could use [bouncycastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html), if you choose to use authenticated encryption.

---

But your encryption code *should produce different results* every time you use it, because you should be using a random IV. You can decrypt the ciphertext correctly if you have the IV. The IV doesn't have to be secret; you could store it next to the ciphertext.

If you were using `mcrypt` with `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`, you could still make your PHP code compatible with C#, as `RijndaelManaged` supports 256 bit block size.

```
symmetricKey.BlockSize = 256;
```

However you shouldn't use `mcrypt` because it's not maintained, and it's deprecated in PHP 7.

Comment: your php script returns "R6CjRlJr+2fXh8ic6JeZBA=="  not "C9xJGa03dRQx9ePm0nLnHg==" please check it.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't use your padding method. I've updated my answer to produce the required result.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the C# end of this question.  However I will point out some information that may be relevant to your problem.

- The descriptions in the RIJNDAEL functions refer to the block size, not the key size.  For example `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` states that you are using a block size of 256. It is not specifying a key size.
- For the openssl AES functions you are specifying a key size.  As an example `aes-256-cbc` specifies you are using a 256 bit key.
- The block size for all the AES functions is a 128 bit.  So you can use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` which matches the AES block size.  You can use a 256 bit key with both the `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` and the `aes-256-cbc` as they are both using the 128 bit block size.
- So for these reasons `aes-256-cbc` can not be used with `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`.  They simply are not the same thing.
- This one is redundant. If you are using the `aes-256-cbc`you need to make sure that you are using a 256 bit key. Obviously make sure that your are using the same key to encrypt and decrypt.  Make sure your IV is the correct IV.  I would make them both static for testing.  Once you get it working tinker around with adding the IV to the cipher string on encrypt and separating the IV from the cipher text on decrypt
- Use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` to generate your 256 bit(32 byte)key.  You can also use `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` to generate your IV.

On a side note.  I would highly recommend using the [LibSodium](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php) library.  It is now native on the latest versions of PHP and has a C# library as well.  You can find it on Github easy enough.

Once you get this going I would look at learning how to Authenticate/Verify your encryption.  Here is a good starting link for that. [Authentication Read](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to store passwords at the database using an reversible algo, passwords should be stored using expensive hashes. You should consider switching your password storage to a hash like Argon2.

Check this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score -1):

mcrypt has been moved. not removed. you may try installing this

```
sudo apt-get -y install gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config
sudo apt-get -y install php7.2-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libmcrypt-dev
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

PS: not tested

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: openssl_encrypt is alternative to mcrypt