# crypto-js encryption not returning same as C# encryption

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, cryptojs

I am trying to convert a C# encryption method in angular by using crypto-js library in my angular project.

Here is the implementation of C# method

```
private const string EncryptionKey = "SomeSecretKEY";
private readonly static byte[] Salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(EncryptionKey.Length.ToString());

public static String EncryptPassword(string password)
{
    var rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
    byte[] plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
    var secretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, Salt);


    using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16)))
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what i an trying in angular

```
var enckey = "SomeSecretKEY";
var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(enckey.length.toString());
var key32Byte = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(enckey, salt, {
    keySize: 256 / 32
});
var iv = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(enckey, salt, {
    keySize: 128 / 32
});
var secret = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("messageforencryption");
var enc = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(secret, key32Byte.toString(), {"iv": iv.toString()});
console.log(enc.toString());
```

I have not access to change the already written C# method.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Taking it one step at a time, have you tested that your code produces the same salt?

Comment: Yes, the salt is also different, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes equivalent is not not there in cryptojs.

Comment: In crypto-js most of the things returning WordArray, so that i am not able to compare with c# getbyte() byte arrays.

Comment: On the C#-side the `PasswordDeriveBytes`-method is used to generate the password, on the JavaScript-side PBKDF2. `PasswordDeriveBytes` is a proprietary MS _extension_ of PBKDF1, which cannot be reduced to PBKDF1 for a key larger than 20 bytes and/or a salt larger than 8 bytes. Therefore a change to PBKDF1 on the JavaScript-side is no solution. Since the C#-code obviously can't be changed, only the (expensive) implementation of the `PasswordDeriveBytes`-functionality on the JavaScript-side remains. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27798812/9014097) `PasswordDeriveBytes` is explained.